# How do you show that $(x-y,y^2)$ is primary in $k[x,y,z]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that $Rad((x-y,y^2))=(x,y)$ which is prime but I can’t conclude that the original ideal is primary. Any quick methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a nice criterion for being primary. (See Dummit and Foote, $\S15.2$ Proposition $19$ for a reference.)

**Proposition**. Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $Q \trianglelefteq R$ be an ideal. Then $Q$ is primary iff every zero divisor in $R/Q$ is nilpotent.

Applying this to your problem, first note that
\begin{align*}
\frac{R}{Q} = \frac{k[x,y,z]}{(x-y,y^2)} \cong \frac{k[y,z]}{(y^2)} \, .
\end{align*}
Suppose $0 \neq \overline{a} \in R/Q$ is a zero divisor, so $\overline{a}\overline{b} = 0$ for some $\overline{b} \neq 0$. Then $ab \in (y^2)$ but $a \notin (y^2)$ and $b \notin (y^2)$, so $y^2 \mid ab$ but $y^2 \nmid a$ and $y^2 \nmid b$. Thus we must have $y \mid a$ and $y \mid b$. Then $a = y a'$ for some $a' \in R$, so $\overline{a}^2 = (\overline{y a'})^2 = 0$.